# Google Tag Manager Event Tracking - Pass a page as a parameter

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track the form submit event on Google Analytics using Google Tag Manager, and I would like to pass the page where the event was triggered as a parameter.

Considering that the form appears on several pages, how can I configure this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could create a macro that grabs the page pathname, and then in the event label, just call that macro.

Comment: This is captured by default, the behavior/events section even has a report called "pages" (you'd have to set event category/action as second dimension). Or you can create a custom report. Is there really a use case that requires to record this information independently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just capture the event without passing the page, then view the pages that event was fired on by viewing the Behaviour > Events > Pages report in Google Analytics.